# Why should we use @Startup for timer service in EJB?

Tags: timer, ejb, scheduling, java-ee-8

I had a service as:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class JobTest {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        timerService.createTimer(0,1000, "Every second timer with no delay");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("execute your job here");
    }

}
```

However, the job wasn't executed. But when added @Startup to the service, the code run as expected. Could you explain why we needed @Startup to use timerService resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB container does not create instances of managed beans unless those are being looked up, injected, or annotated with `@Startup`. The method annotated with `@PostConstruct` is never called for the EJB in the question, therefore the timer is never created, therefore no callbacks occur.

If you **have** to use programmatically created timers (due to delay value coming from the configuration), you need to force the eager initialization - by either annotating the bean with the `@Startup` or injecting it into another `@Startup` bean.

Another option is to use [automatically created timers](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/jakarta-enterprise-beans-spec-core-4.0.html#automatic-timer-creation) by annotating a method with the `@Schedule` annotation, though the timer configuration is hardcoded in this case.